# Value is in DataFrame column, but .loc[] function returns nothing?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame named "returns" that has a column 'permno'. The code `15372.0 in returns['permno']` returns True, telling me that 15372.0 is in the column 'permno'. However, `returns[returns['permno']==15372.0]` returns an empty Series, suggesting that it cannot find any values in the DataFrame where the permno is 15372.0. Similarly, I have a column 'dlycaldt' that stores dates as strings; the code `'2021-01-04' in returns['dlycaldt']` returns False, but the code `returns[returns['dlycaldt']=='2021-01-04']` returns a large DataFrame. Can someone help me reconcile these results?

I wrote the following code snippet to find if 15372.0 was really in the DataFrame or not:

```
is_present = returns['permno'].isin([15372.0])
if is_present.any():
    print("At least one row has the value 15372.0 in the 'permno' column.")
else:
    print("No rows have the value 15372.0 in the 'permno' column.")
```

Running this code told me that no rows have the value 15372.0. If this is the case, how come the initial line of code is returning True?